# How to import model with associations using rails_admin_import gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, import, rails-admin

I'm trying to import my database, which have `Project` and `Technology` models (project has many technologies). Each project should have at least 1 technology. I use rails_admin_import gem for this task. As far as I understand, during project import gem is supposed to find associations of the model (technologies in my case) and connect them to model if they exist.

Everything is fine when I import technologies, but as soon as I'm importing projects, I receive this error for each of the projects:

```
Failed to create Project_1: Technologies minimum allowed: 1
```

I tried to import projects before importing technologies and after that, added to both of them mapping key, but nothing changed:

```
config.model 'Project' do
  import do
    mapping_key :name
    include_all_fields
  end
end
config.model 'Technology' do
  import do
    mapping_key :name
    include_all_fields
  end
end
```

Maybe anyone can help me and say what am I doing wrong?

**UPD:** The problem is that I exported data using default rails_admin export, which saves data in csv like that:

[image]

But rails_admin_import expects data in this format:

[image]

So I need to change my question. How should I configure rails_admin so that it would export data in a format accepted by rails_admin_import?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this, but probably not the best one.

I used `before_import_associations` method of rails_admin_import to create needed `technologies` key manually.

```
def before_import_associations(record)
  record[:technologies] = record[:name_technologies].split(',')
end
```